# SSRS 2016: Can't set a default parameter value

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I’m having a problem selecting a default parameter based on previous cascading parameters.

My report has the following parameters, all required:

•   Start Date (Defaults to yesterday)

•   End Date  (Defaults to yesterday)

•   District (Where they worked)

•   Field Reps (Who worked)

When the user selects one or more Districts, a stored procedure fills the FieldReps parameter selector with a list of workers who worked in that district *during that date range.* That list can change from day to day, which makes it hard to set up a subscription to this report.

My solution was to add a field rep with a code of 'ANY' to the FieldReps data set and set it as the default. That way, the report will only include any workers who worked during the date range. This option makes it possible to subscribe to this report. If the user selects 'ANY', the report will return a valid list of workers for the default date range, which is 'yesterday.'

But: I want 'ANY' to be selected by default. But it doesn’t work!

My source dataset provides available values for the FieldReps parameter. (Value is FieldRepCode, Label is FieldRep) An ‘ANY’ entry is added to the top of the list by the stored procedure.

If I specify 'AL06' as the default value (that field rep is in the list), it is selected by default. But if I specify 'ANY', no default is selected.

I’ve checked to ensure 'ANY' has no leading/trailing spaces. I even suspected case sensitivity, so I ensured the case matched. I used an expression (="ANY") to set the default value. None if it made a difference.

Any ideas why this isn’t working?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the Value and Label of `'ANY'`?

Comment: Sounds like you've tried most of the usual suspects when it comes to troubleshooting this sort of error, but have you verified that the value you pass to the procedure from the "ANY" option is the same as the default?  When specifying the default, you want to match the value of the available option, not necessarily the name.  To clarify, does your procedure to select all reps handle the value "ANY"?  Or does it expect some other value?  Perhaps a snippet of the proc and a few images of the report design could help diagnose the issue.

Comment: The value of ANY is just that - a string. The FieldRepCode is a varchar(10) that contains a string code. I added 'ANY' to the list. 

I specify date range and district, which should give me a list of workers for that window. I add 'ANY' to the results in the stored procedure. It shows up as a choice in the picker. 

I'll work on posting some images here...